# EditText doing reverse to string

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` and displaying values in that. I am using a `StringBuilder`

```
str = str.insert(0, value); 
System.out.println("str2:-"+str);
showOutputEdit.setText(str.toString());
```

If I use simple digits, it displays the digits correctly like

```
input:- 1,2,3
ouput:- 3,2,1
```

but if use any symbol, they get **reversed** in the `EditText` but not in android **log**

```
input:- 1,+,9
edittext output:- 1,+,9
log output:-  9,+,1
```

I am confused, why are they getting reversed in `EditText`?

```
str2:-٩+١value + showOutputEdit.getText().toString()٩+١
Edittext:-  9+1
```

Comment: What is your system language? It is possible that `EditText` is detecting that you are typing a language (such as Arabic) from right-to-left and hence insert at beginning (left) is inserting it at the end (right).

Comment: utf-8 is system language

Answer (score 2):

Your `insert` code is wrong, if you give 0 as the position to insert, it will insert the character at the begginning. Instead you should do:

```
showOutputEdit.setText(value + showOutputEdit.getText().toString());
```

Comment: but i want to insert a begining. i am using Arabic format

Comment: Oh sorry, when you said why is it reversing the text, i tought you don't want to reverse it. Sorry. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I think you should use native RTL support on Arabic language and put all the chars at the end. It will automatically display right to left.